# Change custom Product taxonomy to WooCommerce Product Taxonomy

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a site that's using Toolset Types to generate a 'Product' post type and a 'Product Categories' taxonomy (product-category). Now I am adding WooCommerce to the site and need to set the 'Product Categories' taxonomy to the WooCommerce taxonomy for products, product_cat. WooCommerce already picked up the Product post type and all of the product are showing up in WooCommerce Products. I just need to get the categories to appear there also.

I tried using a plugin called Taxonomy Switcher and also an SQL query that updated the taxonomy field in the wp_term_taxonomy table. Both of these moved product-categories to product_cat but only for the parent categories, removing the children.

`UPDATE wp_term_taxonomy SET taxonomy='genre' WHERE taxonomy='category'`

How can I change the custom product-category taxonomy to WooCommerce Product Taxonomy, product_cat?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_product_taxonomies', 0 );

function create_product_taxonomies() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Genre', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Genres', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Genres', 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Genre', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Genres', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Genres:', 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Genres', 'textdomain' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Genres', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Genres', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Genre Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Genres', 'textdomain' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'genres' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'genre', array( 'product' ), $args );


}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I was able to resolve my issue by disabling WooCommerce, changing the 'product-category' taxonomy in Toolset Types to the WooCommerce taxonomy 'product_cat', disabling Toolset Types and then reactivating WooCommerce.